# Why standard deviation is calculated the way it is calculated?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I do not have any problems with degree of freedoms or why squaring is better than taking absolute values but I have more fundamental problem with understanding of why formula looks this way.

$\frac{\sqrt{{\sum_i^n (x_{i}-\overline{x})^{2}}{}}}{\sqrt{n}}$

Why number of items in sample is also square rooted?
I understand that this is related to Variance formula but what's the sense to take the square root of **n**? Unlike deviances it was not squared in the first place.

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 2):

The standard deviation is simply the square root of the variance. It is not defined by the formula above but rather by $\sigma = \sqrt{var}$. This means that any value that is present in the variance will (probably) be present in the standard deviation.

As $n$ is part of the definition for the variance (see e.g. [Variance of a discrete random variable on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Discrete_random_variable)) it is also in the standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $n$ samples, half of which equal $-1$ and half of which equal $1$.
Then
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} = 1$$ no matter what $n$ is. This makes sense: the "spread" of the data is the same, regardless of whether the sample size is $10$ or $10000$.

If you don't take the square root of $n$, then you get
$$\frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
which shrinks to zero as $n \to \infty$, which would not really make sense for a notion of spread.